# Замена символа "_" на пробел

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, как произвести замену символа "_" на пробел в выводимых файлах? Например: Aston_martin_lagonda_taraf_2015 на Aston martin lagonda taraf 2015

```
<?php 

$dir = "album/";
$name = scandir($dir);

for($i = 2; $i <= (sizeof($name) - 1); $i++) {
    echo "<a target=_blank href='" . $dir . $name[$i] . "'>" . $name[$i] . "</a><br/>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Используйте ф-ю [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php):

```
echo str_replace('_', ' ', 'Aston_martin_lagonda_taraf_2015');
// Выведет Aston martin lagonda taraf 2015
```

Comment: Спасибо! Сработало.

Answer (score -2):

или как вариант [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
preg_replace("/_/"," ",'Aston_martin_lagonda_taraf_2015');
//string 'Aston martin lagonda taraf 2015' (length=31)
```

Comment: Регулярки медленнее